# How to get the first day of next week?

Tags: java, date

With the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class you get the methods `firstDayOfNextYear()`, `firstDayOfNextMonth()`. How can I calculate the `firstDayOfNextWeek()`?

Comment: In addition to the current answers : if you're looking for an i18n way to retrieve which day-of-the-week is the first day of weeks you can use `WeekFields. getFirstDayOfWeek()`

Comment: Yeah, I found that as well on one of the stackoverflow questions for calculating the first and last date of current week. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
```

or

```
TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
```

If the first day of the week depends on user locale:

```
TemporalAdjusters.next(WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek())
```

(Credit to @Aaron por pointing it out)

Comment: My comment was on the short side, but `getFirstDayOfWeek()` is an instance method rather than a static one, you need to obtain an instance through `WeekFields.of(Locale l)` first. Also I've tested it a bit and I'm surprised by the first-day-of-week returned by `WeekFields.of(Locale.FRANCE).getFirstDayOfWeek()` which should return MONDAY but seems to return SUNDAY (see [here](https://ideone.com/UtU19N))... Works well for US/UK though

Comment: On Ideone i got the same value for france, but running it on my local environment I got monday: https://imgur.com/a/VLoYpS4

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this class before but I found it very interesting as I read through its Javadoc.

For the question, firstDayOfNextWeek means next Monday. 
So one could say:

```
private TemporalAdjusters firstDayOfNextWeek() {
  return TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
}
```

EDIT:

It is more complete when it works with a Locale object:

```
private TemporalAdjusters firstDayOfNextWeek(Locale locale) {
  return TemporalAdjusters.next(WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek());
}
```

Thanks @Aaron for notifying about this localization issue.

Comment: "firstDayOfNextWeek means next Monday" depends where you live. In particular that's incorrect in the US where Sunday is considered the first day of the week (although it's part of the weekend, yes...)